# Deleting Duplicate Characters in a String

Tags: java, duplicates

Hi I need to fix this code to delete characters that repeat immediately in the string. For example: If I type aaabbbcccdeeff, it has to return abcdef at the end. However on the computer in class it returns something of a, "out of range (number)", the number being dependent on how many characters I used. On my mac however it just returns a number like 3 as an output and gives no error message. I am on Eclipse.

Please help, I didn't understand what the professor said and he rarely helps. The code is (somewhat helped by professor):

```
package firstProgramSimple;

import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SimpleVersion {

  public static void main(String[] args) {  

    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System. in );
    System.out.println("Entre String");
    String string = kb.nextLine();
    //System.out.println(string);           
    int length = string.length();
    for (int i = 1; i < length; i++) {
      if (string.charAt(i) != string.charAt(i - 1)) {
        System.out.print(i);
      } else if (string.charAt(i) != string.charAt(i)) {
        System.out.print(i);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: By the way, I am on my first semester of computer Programming, so take it easy on me. I have to use very basic functions and commands. And need good explanation. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you put each character in a `Set` (does not allow duplicate) of `String`?

Comment: Your `else if` condition doesn't look correct. You're checking if `string.charAt(i)` is not equal to itself, which is always false.

Comment: The professor is actually doing you a favour by not "helping".  To become an effective programmer, you must learn to work these things out for yourself.  And the best way to learn that is to do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing your loop counter and not the value of the char at the position of the counter:

```
System.out.print(i);
```

Should be:

```
System.out.print(string.charAt(i));
```

You will get an arrayOutOfBoundsException for inputs of size < 2.  You might want to add this line once you have the string initialised:

```
if(string == null || string.length() < 2){
    System.out.println(string);
    return;
}
```

Something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {  

    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System. in );
    System.out.println("Entre String");
    String string = kb.nextLine();

    //System.out.println(string);           
    int length = string.length();
    if(length < 2) {
        System.out.println(string);
        return;
    }

    System.out.print(string.charAt(0));
    for (int i = 1; i < length; i++) {
        if (string.charAt(i) != string.charAt(i - 1)) {
            System.out.print(string.charAt(i));
          } 
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried adding the system.out.println(string.charAt) but it just returns numbers. I entered kkeevviinn and it returns 2468. I need it to return "Kevin"

Comment: Your string is inialised once it is assigned a value with the call: String string = kb.nextLine();

Comment: @StuPointerException It's not necessary to check if `length < 2` since the `for`-loop won't be entered for lengths less than 2. After all, the condition `i < length` would be `false` from the very beginning.

Comment: @Lone - That's very true :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to print `string.charAt(i)` and not `i`.

Also, this piece of code is unnecessary since it will always return false:

```
//string.charAt(i) is always equal to itself
else if ( string.charAt(i) != string.charAt( i )) {
    System.out.print(i);
```

Since you start at `i = 1`, the `char` at index `0` will never be printed. Before the `for`-loop, you should add this line:

```
System.out.print(string.charAt(0));
```

Comment: Thanks, the program now runs perfectly. I also think I have a good idea of why it wasn't working. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @user2339846 As StuPointerException pointed out, the main issue was that you were printing the index of the `char` (i.e. the counter), and not the `char` itself.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your `for` loop like bellow:

```
    System.out.print(string.charAt(0));
    for (int i = 1; i < length; i++) {
        if (string.charAt(i) != string.charAt(i - 1)) {
            System.out.print(string.charAt(i));
        }
    }
```

The idea is, print the beginning character first, then print the character at ***i* th** position, only if its different then its previous character. Simple!